# SAS, elegant code, data name.

Tags: sas

I have a series of data set, so I name all temp data as temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5.......Is there any more elegant way to do that? For example, just call the last generated data directly, or some method I cannot even think of.

```
data temp1;
 set test;
  A=sum(A,B,C)
run;
proc sort data=temp1 
by E;
run;


data temp2;
set temp1;
retain co_date;
E=M
run;



proc sql;
create table temp3 as
select
*
,sum(h) as p
,sum(a) as m
,sum(r) as c
from temp2
group by v;
quit;



data temp4;
 set temp3;
 if b=1;
run;
```

Comment: I usually don't use temp unless it's throwaway but a simple naming system goes a long way. I'll usually use something more descriptive like health1, health2, ... healthn. This allows you to reference the data sets as a list or short cut so its a really good way to design your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS already has a method like that which uses names `DATA1`, `DATA2`, etc.  You just leave the name blank and SAS uses the next one in the series.

```
2    data ;
3     set sashelp.class;
4    run;

NOTE: There were 19 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.
NOTE: The data set WORK.DATA1 has 19 observations and 5 variables.
```

It stores the name of the most recently created dataset into the `SYSLAST` macro variable.  So you could use that where you want to reference your previous output as your input.

```
data ;
  set &syslast ;
  if age < 14 ;
run;
```

Or you could use your own macro variable to count, but you will need to increment it yourself.

```
%let dsnum=1;
data temp&dsnum;
  set test;
  A=sum(A,B,C)
run;
proc sort data=temp&dsnum ; 
  by E;
run;

data temp%eval(&dsnum+1);
  set temp&dsnum;
  retain co_date;
  E=M
run;
%let dsnum=%eval(&dsnum+1);

proc sql;
create table temp%eval(&dsnum+1) as
 select
  *
  ,sum(h) as p
  ,sum(a) as m
  ,sum(r) as c
 from temp&dsnum
 group by v
;
quit;
%let dsnum=%eval(&dsnum+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A Good Practice for naming SAS work tables in an ETL|Data Integration process/schedule: is to prefix your table name with the type of processing that created it along with the name of source table/context.

Examples:

- Using PROC SQL to join customer tables: SQL_JOIN_CUST_BASKET
- Extract/Filter on Outdoor products: EXT_PROD_OUTDOOR
- Appending two tables 2017/18: APPND_SALES_2017_18
- Sort Sales by Customer ID in 2017: SORT_CUST_Sales_ID

The above standard will make it easier for others to understand your code, easier to debug and will help you remember what your code does when revisiting.

Note: SAS table names can't be more that 32 characters; you can remove vowels from names to make them shorter.

Comment: You can also use numeric suffixed data set names and using the data set option `label=` to associate up to 200 characters.  `Proc SQL; create table data07 (label="SQL_JOIN_CUST_BASKET") ...`